# Constrain what files you can see with angularjs ng-flow

Tags: angularjs, flow-js

I'm trying to implement a flow file uploader but I can't see how to make it that the user can only select image files. I copied the example so I have

```
<div
    data-flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"
    flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]"
    name="introduction-picture-upload">
```

But I still see all files available in my upload window, not just images. Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's

```
<button
    flow-btn
    flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">
```

Not well documented !

Comment: Although I am still not clear how you would have only PNGs and JPGs for example

Comment: You can use ``flow-attrs="{accept:['image/png','image/jpeg']`` for allowing PNGs and JPGs.